# how to write test class for inserting null values in page?

Tags: visualforce, unit-test, code-coverage

I have one visualforce page from where i am inserting contacts. After inserting contacts i am assigning null value to the fields of the page. how to cover the code for inserting those null values.. can somebody please give any idea about it.

```
public without sharing class ReferalAccessclass {
public String inputID{get; set;}
public String firstName{get; set;}
public String lastName{get; set;}
public String email{get; set;}
public String phone{get; set;}
public Decimal exp{get; set;}
public String location{get; set;}
public contact con{get;set;}

Public attachment objAttachment{get; set;}

public ReferalAccessclass(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
{ 

    objAttachment = new Attachment();

}

public Pagereference saveInformation()
{
try{
    IF(inputID != 'NULL'){
    con = [SELECT ID,Name,FirstName,LastName,Email,Phone,Years_of_Experience__c,Location__c FROM Contact where ID =: inputID ];

    con.FirstName = firstName;
    con.LastName = lastName;
    con.Email = email;
    con.Phone = phone; 
    }
    update con;
    objAttachment.ParentId = con.id;
    Insert objAttachment;

    inputID = NULL;
    firstName= NULL;
    LastName = NULL;
    Email = NULL;
    Phone = NULL;
    location = NULL;
    exp=NULL;
    ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM, 'Thank you for your valuable response');
            ApexPages.addMessage(msg); 

    return Null;
   }
  catch(exception e){
  ApexPages.addMessages(e);
   return null;
  } 



}

}
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest 
    public class TestReferalAccessclass1 { 
    static testMethod  void ReferalAccessclassMethod() { 

        Contact c=new Contact(
            FirstName='fname',
            LastName = 'lname',
            Email = 'email@gmail.com',
            Phone = '9743800309',
            Years_of_Experience__c=3,
            Location__c='Delhi'); 
            {
        insert c; 
        Test.StartTest(); 
        System.AssertNotEquals(Null, c.Id); 

        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(c);
        ReferalAccessclass refClass = new ReferalAccessclass(sc);
        refClass.inputID = c.id;
        refClass.firstName = 'abc';
        refClass.lastName = 'dwg';
        refClass.email = 'abc@email.com';
        refClass.phone = '9898989898';
        refClass.location='ggg';
        refClass.exp=3;
        refClass.con = c;
        refClass.saveInformation();

        ApexPages.Message[] pageMessages = ApexPages.getMessages();
        System.assertNotEquals(0, pageMessages.size());

        ApexPages.StandardController sc1 = new ApexPages.StandardController(c);
        ReferalAccessclass refClass1 = new ReferalAccessclass(sc1);
        refClass1.inputID = null;
        refClass1.firstName = null;
        refClass1.lastName = null;
        refClass1.email = null;
        refClass1.phone = null;
        refClass1.location=null;
        refClass1.exp=null;
        refClass1.con = c;
        refClass1.saveInformation();
        ApexPages.Message[] pageMessages1 = ApexPages.getMessages();
        System.assertNotEquals(1, pageMessages1.size());

        }
        Test.StopTest();
            }
             }
```

Comment: What is the problem in covering those lines? Please share your test class code as well.

Comment: @Mr.Frodo i have updated the apex class and test class as well. My code coverage is 71% upto now. but i want to know how to cover those null values. only the null values are not covering. If you could suggest something then i can learn

Comment: @Priya How is the inputId being passed to the controller from the VF page. I do not see it being set anywhere? Is it a URL param?

Comment: I think after calling `saveInformation()` these lines should get covered automatically. If  this is not happening, it means that it is throwing some exception and going into the catch block. Write debug statement in catch block and check what is the exception.

Comment: Also @Priya, in your code you are checking whether if it is equal to the string 'NULL'. I think you should be checking for the value null.

Comment: @RichardN i am checking for the value null only right.. can you please ellaborate

Comment: @Priya inputId should be `public Id inputId { get; set; }`; this would have immediately thrown an error to let you know that you did something wrong. The value `'NULL'` is a four-character string "null", while `null` without the quotes means literally "there is no value here."

Comment: @sfdcfox ok i got it, but i have a doubt.. at the end of the apex class i am assigning null values to the fields, so when testing those lines i should enter null only or i cam test with any values? may be this question is soo basic but i am very confused in writing test classes..

Comment: @Priya there is a difference between the value NULL and the string 'NULL'.. One is the value of null while in your code you are check the value against a string called "NULL". So in your code change this line `IF(inputID != 'NULL'){` to `IF(inputID != NULL){` . See how I have removed the single quotes around  "NULL"

Comment: @Priya Your code has numerous problems besides what we've mentioned here. Without seeing your page's code, it's hard to tell why you'd write a controller this way. It's exceptionally unusual, and I suspect there's a better way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Priya in addition to all the others. Your issue is also the insert of the attachment. You are not assigning any of the required fields and thus an exception is thrown when you attempt to insert and the catch block is entered

Comment: You should also be checking the vale of the page messages not just size. An error message would pass that assert. Even better check the value of the updated contact to ensure is was updated then the page message is irrelevant

Answer (score 2):

Your immediate problem is this line of code here:

```
if(inputId != 'NULL') {
```

What's happening is that you assigned the literal null value to inputId, so it's not "NULL" (a 4-character String). The next line tries to execute the query for the contact, and there's no matching rows, so it throws an exception.

At minimum, you should change `public String inputId { get; set; }` to `public Id inputId { get; set; }`, which would have given you a TypeException when you tried to compare the value; this would have let you know that something weird was going on.

This means you'd next want to change your if statement:

```
if(inputId != null) {
```

You have a number of other issues with your code and the unit test. For example, you're not saving `exp` or `location` back to the contact record; this data would be lost.

Your unit test is assigning a value to `con`, which is useless at best, but is also confusing, because you don't appear to use `con` to get your input data anyways, so `Contact con` should simply be a local variable in your method:

```
public void saveInformation() {
    if(inputId != null) {
        Contact con = new Contact(Id = inputId, FirstName = firstName ...);
        update con;
```

Your unit test should not be altering the internal state of the object, and that variable should be private to the object.

It would be a lot easier if you used `con` directly with your data bindings, instead of passing variables around. Here's a version of your class that's less error prone:

```
public without sharing class ReferalAccessclass {
    public Id inputId { get; set; }
    public contact con { get;set; }
    Public attachment objAttachment { get; set; }

    public ReferalAccessclass() { 
        con = new Contact();
        objAttachment = new Attachment();
    }

    public void saveInformation() {
        if(inputId != null) {
            objAttachment.ParentId = con.Id = inputId;
            Savepoint sp = Database.setSavePoint();
            try {
                update con;
                insert objAttachment;
            } catch(DmlException e) {
                Database.rollback(sp);
                ApexPages.addMessages(e);
                return;
            }
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM, 'Thank you for your valuable response'));
            con = new Contact();
            objAttachment = new Attachment();
        }
    }
}
```

You'll have to fix your page code and unit test appropriately.